# how to use headers in fetch on React-Native or Expo

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native, fetch, expo

I want to communicate with the server.

In order to communicate with the server, two items must be added to `headers`.

> Note: The key value written is not the actual key value.

- api_key:  "abcdegeg123456842536ebebeb1yeyju",
- game_key: "abcdegeg123456842536ebebeb1yeyju"

The code I tried to communicate with:

```js
checkNickName = async () => {
    fetch("http://192.168.0.44:11000/v1/point/auth/change_nickname", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        wallet_address: "0f8751828af26816ef996c37e611b945304a6e99",
        new_nickname: this.state.nickname
      }),
      headers: {
        // "Content-Type": "application/json"
        api_key: "abcdegeg123456842536ebebeb1yeyju",
        game_key: "abcdegeg123456842536ebebeb1yeyju"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response:" + response);
        console.log(response.resultCode);
        if (response.resultCode == "S000") {
          Alert.alert("info","scess");
        } else alert(response.result);
      })
      //console.log("Success:", JSON.stringify(response))
      .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
  };
```

But this is not working

> Error:, [TypeError: Network request failed]

How can I communicate with the server? Is there another way?

thank you in advance

Comment: do you test network call in iOS or Android?

Comment: @QuokMoon This is normal now, but the value is null when receiving data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It was a mistake in my address,

but the server receiving the data says the data is null. How can we solve the problem?

> I solved it by using `formdata`.

usePage.js

```js
 async checkNickName() {
    let formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append(
      "wallet_address",
      "gBx0f8751828af26816ef996c37e611b945304a6e99"
    );
    formdata.append("new_nickname", this.state.nickname);
    fetch("http://192.168.0.26:11000/v1/point/auth/change_nickname", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formdata,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        api_key: "5b95576338b1eb1c53a1ae3f904dc7c5",
        game_key: "bf61b73dd871c2973188706d813002c2"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.resultCode);
        if (response.resultCode == "S002") {
          AsyncStorage.setItem("gbrickobj", this.state.gbrickobj);
          AsyncStorage.setItem("nickname", this.state.nickname);
          this.props.navigation.navigate("RegisterSecurity");
        } else if (response.resultCode == "S001") {
          this.setState({
            checknick: "this nickname already use nickname."
          });
        } else {
          Alert.alert("info", "check address.");
        }
      })
      .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error));
  }
```